# Nested jade via conditional logic

Tags: pug, express

I've got a result set of json data that is retrieved that is called data_list.  I want to iterate through it and pull out its name field and embed it it in a twitter bootstrap grid metaphor.  The output of this would look something like the following:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span4">Name 1</div>
   <div class="span4">Name 2</div>
   <div class="span4">Name 3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="span4">Name 4</div>
   <div class="span4">Name 5</div>
   <div class="span4">Name 6</div>
</div>
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to accomplish this in Jade.  I know how to iterate through my data with

```
- for (var key in data_list)
    div.span4
        p= data_list[key].name
```

What I don't know how to do is to inject the  in for every three records of data and have it surround those three records.  I know how to capture every three records via

```
- if ((key % 3) == 0)
    .row
```

but I can only get it to output a  but I can't get it to surround the other rows.  Any suggestions would be greatly welcome.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same problem yesterday using bootstrap.

I solved it this way:

```
each element, i in dataset
  if i % 3 == 0
    div.row
      each elementInRow, j in dataset.slice(i, i+3)
        div.span4
          ...cell code...
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Great solution, thank you. I've been racking my brain a long time.

Comment: Thank you :) years later, this still functions perfectly